# Coupon Collector Problem - Minimum Number of Selections

Tags: coupon-collector

If things are chosen randomly from n possible choices, then **number of selections** that all possible choices are selected at least once is approximated by $nH_n$, where $H_n$ is $nth$ Harmonic Number.

The lower bound of **number of selections** seems to be $n$ i.e in a rare event, one may be able to select all choices at least once after n selections.

**Is this possible? is this lower bound right?**

**What is the likelihood of such a rare event?**

**What is the probability that a collection of size x has all the possible choices at least once**

**What is the probability P(x, n) such that it takes x or less than x draws to obtain all n distinct elements, when drawing with replacement from a set of n distinct elements.**

I ran a simulation 10000 times for n=100 ($nH_n$=521), it shows that  minimum_number_of_selections = 279 and maximum_number_of_selections = 1302.

Comment: The lower bound on the number of selections (not the expected number) is indeed $n$, as you need one of each of $n$ types.  Your $279$ is higher than $100$ because you didn't try enough.  The chance of getting $100$ different ones in $100$ tries is *very* small.  What have you tried?

Comment: i ran simulation 10000 times (question updated).

Comment: Don't put such a big $n$ in your simulation. It will "never" be achieved with that :DDDDD!!!!!!!!

Comment: Btw, it isn't the **expected** number of selections, that's in question here. That is just a number, it doesn't vary. You should say "the number of selections" (before seeing all choices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $n$ is possible to achieve if all the $n$ first draws are different.

The probability is $\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}$ because you need to get a permutation of the objects but all in all you can get any sequence.